# Android Cursor error - Make sure cursor is initialised correctly

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-cursor

I've set up a Cursor which I want to return a listview of contacts who have a phone number. So, in each cell, I'll have the contact name and then phone number underneath. This code mostly does the job :

```
// this query only return contacts with phone number and is not duplicated
        phones = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
//                we only want contacts that have a name and a phone number. If they have a phone number, the value is 1 (if not, it is 0)
                ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '" + ("1") + "'" + " AND " + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1",
                null,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
```

And then when it comes to extracting information and putting it in each cell :

```
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {

            String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
```

I'm getting an error, part of the code which is:

```
04-07 10:43:46.489  17742-17760/com.example.chris.contactlistcustomlistview E/CursorWindow﹕ Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 134 rows, 34 columns.
04-07 10:43:46.489  17742-17760/com.example.chris.contactlistcustomlistview W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416168e0)
04-07 10:43:46.489  17742-17760/com.example.chris.contactlistcustomlistview E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
            at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
```

So, the cursor is hopping from `Contacts.Contracts` to `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone` and it doesn't like it. But how else can I get the phone number of a user ? As far as I know, it's not in `ContactsContracts.Contacts`. Should I reinitialize the cursor or something before going to `CommonDataKinds` and how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (phones != null) {
    phones.moveToFirst();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling phones.moveToFirst() before phones.moveToNext()? It moves to the first row. This is because your current query returns a Cursor object positioned before the first entry.

You can try writing:

```
if (phones.moveToFirst()) {

       while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                    // etc
```

Comment: thanks PlanetAstro, but that didn't fix it. Still same error. I believe movetonext and movetofirst do the same thing anyway, when starting from the first position in a table.